# Quasi birth death process with Erlang interarrival time distribution

Tags: birth-death-process

I am struggling with modeling a system as a quasi birth death process, since the interarrival times are not Poisson but Erlang distributed with parameters $n = \lambda = 2$. Is this even possible? Could you help me out?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are the death times distributed as?